# How many types of charging ports do Nintendo handhelds have?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, hardware, nintendo-ds, nintendo-dsi

I'm sorting through my old Nintendo handhelds and have found that many of them use different charging cables. I've seen at least four different types:

- Nintendo Switch & Switch Lite
- Nintendo DSi XL, 3DS XL, and New 3DS XL.
- Nintendo DS Lite
- Nintendo DS

This leads me to question if there are other chargers I'll need to manage if I pick up other models of Nintendo handheld. (DSi, 3DS, New 3DS, 2DS, Game Boy Advance SP, Game Boy Micro, etc).

How many different types of charging ports are there between the different models of Nintendo Game Boy, DS, and 3DS models? Which model uses which type of charger?

Comment: Note: I only mentioned Nintendo handhelds to limit the question scope. For controllers and consoles, I've seen unique chargers for the Wii U Gamepad, the Wii U, and the Wii. The SNES/N64/GameCube/PS1/PS2/PS3 share a cable. The Switch Pro Controller uses USB-C like the Switch.

Comment: 3DS, New 3DS and 2DS share the same port used by 3DS XL

Comment: This feels like it can answer your questions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6FcLwmNHv4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 5 different chargers, one for each of these groups:

- Gameboy Micro
- GBA SP & Nintendo DS
- Nintendo DS Lite
- Nintendo DSi, DSi XL and the entire (New) 2/3DS family.
- The entire Nintendo Switch family (which uses a standard USB-C cable, you can just use one if you have any USB-C device chargers).

Comment: Can you list the other types of chargers needed for the first 4 items? I think they are proprietary some of them. Please state which are.

Comment: All of the chargers are proprietary, expect the USB-C ones used for the Switch.

Comment: There are USB versions some of them but you'll have to look at 3rd party stuff since Nintendo never made USB charging cable of any of there other devices. I have a USB to 3DS cable that works wonders with all the USB packs and chargers that I own.